# Database schema versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

At the moment I am using code first entity. I have added a backup / restore feature to my application which basically does a full database backup / restore using T-SQL.

To avoid someone trying to restore a backup for an older version with different schema, I want to restrict this feature so the restore will only be applied if the schema of the backup file is the same.

What is a good way of dealing with this? First thing that comes into mind is adding a version to the database. Is there a nice way to add versioning?

Answer (score 0):

Database schema changes are stored in__MigrationsHistory (for CodeFirst). It's EF internal versioning mechanism.  Use it.